# curl_easy_perform segmentation fault on Linux

Tags: c++, libcurl

I am working on a c++ app which uses curl in order to an HTTP GET request. It works perfectly fine on Windows but on Linux (CentOS 7) I get a segmentation fault when curl_easy_cleanup is used.

Below is my code

```
CURL* curl = NULL;
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl == NULL)
    {

        this->getBitsLibrary()->writeToLog("Failed to init curl");
        this->getBitsLibrary()->setAlarm("CrashInfo", Alarms::AlarmLevel::Critical, "Failed to init curl for IP lookup");
        return;
    }

    stringstream urlstream;
    string iplookupURL;
    //curlResponse = "";
    urlstream << StaticSettings::IP_Lookup::ipLookupURL << "/" << clientIP << "?access_key="<<StaticSettings::IP_Lookup::api_key;
    iplookupURL = urlstream.str();
    logstream << "Using URL " << iplookupURL << " for IP lookup";
    this->getBitsLibrary()->writeToLog(logstream.str(), "CrashInfo", "performIPLookup");
    logstream.clear();
    logstream.str(string());
    //string response = "";
    this->curlResponse = new string();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, iplookupURL.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void*)this);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &curlStaticCallback);



    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
if (res != CURLE_OK)
    {
        logstream << "Failed to perform IP lookup using curl";
        this->getBitsLibrary()->writeToLog(logstream.str(), "CrashInfo", "performIPLookup");
        this->getBitsLibrary()->setAlarm("CrashInfo", Alarms::AlarmLevel::Warning, "Failed to perform IP Lookup. Curl error");
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        return;
    }

    int httpResponseCode = 0;
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &httpResponseCode);
    if (httpResponseCode == 200)
    {

        if (!this->curlResponse->empty())
        {
            this->getBitsLibrary()->writeToLog("Processing response for IP lookup");
            rapidjson::Document jsonObject;
            jsonObject.Parse(this->curlResponse->c_str());

            const rapidjson::Value& countryValue = jsonObject["country_name"];
            if (!countryValue.IsNull())
            {
                string country = string(jsonObject["country_name"].GetString());
                this->setCountry(!country.empty() ? country : "N/A");
            }
            else
            {
                this->setCountry("N/A");
            }

            const rapidjson::Value& cityValue = jsonObject["city"];
            if (!cityValue.IsNull())
            {
                string city = string(jsonObject["city"].GetString());
                this->setCity(!city.empty() ? city : "N/A");
            }
            else
            {
                this->setCity("N/A");
            }

            this->getBitsLibrary()->writeToLog("IPLookup performed successfully", "CrashInfo", "performIPLookup");
        }
delete this->curlResponse;
    this->curlResponse = NULL;
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

Due the curl being a C library, I've created a static function (outside of the C++ class) as follows:

```
size_t curlStaticCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void * userp)
{
    CrashInfo *crashInfo = (CrashInfo*)userp;
    crashInfo->curlResponseWriteCallback(contents, size, nmemb, userp);
    return size * nmemb;
}
```

The above static function called by the WRITEFUNCTION in curl. I get the class object and then call the C++ function which is as follows:

```
size_t CrashInfo::curlResponseWriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    curlResponse->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}
```

As mentioned above, this works perfectly fine on Windows but on Linux it works fine where I get the expected response the URL, but when `curl_easy_cleanup` is called I then get a segmentation fault which contains the following stack:

```
#0  0x00007fe7f45ff2ad in ?? () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00007fe7f4661c03 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x000000000043f773 in WebManager::CrashInfo::performIPLookup (this=0x7fe7d00020d0, clientIP="192.168.1.96") at CrashInfo.cpp:732
#3  0x000000000043aeb0 in WebManager::CrashInfo::processCrashInfo (this=0x7fe7d00020d0, httpRequest=0x7fe7d00008f0) at CrashInfo.cpp:308
#4  0x00000000004396ee in WebManager::CrashInfo::CrashInfo (this=0x7fe7d00020d0, httpRequest=0x7fe7d00008f0) at CrashInfo.cpp:50
#5  0x000000000046ce23 in WebManager::WebProcessor::processWebSocketData (this=0x7fe7ed841a60, clientpointer=0x7fe7e40008c0, ipAddress=0x7fe7ed8426b8 "192.168.1.96") at WebProcessor.cpp:71
#6  0x0000000000473bd6 in std::_Mem_fn<void (WebManager::WebProcessor::*)(void*, char*)>::operator()<int*, char*, void>(WebManager::WebProcessor*, int*&&, char*&&) const (this=0x7fe7e4000948, __object=0x7fe7ed841a60)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:601
#7  0x00000000004739fd in std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (WebManager::WebProcessor::*)(void*, char*)> (WebManager::WebProcessor*, int*, char*)>::_M_invoke<0ul, 1ul, 2ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul, 1ul, 2ul>) (this=0x7fe7e4000930)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:1732
#8  0x00000000004737fd in std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (WebManager::WebProcessor::*)(void*, char*)> (WebManager::WebProcessor*, int*, char*)>::operator()() (this=0x7fe7e4000930) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:1720
#9  0x000000000047372e in std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (WebManager::WebProcessor::*)(void*, char*)> (WebManager::WebProcessor*, int*, char*)> >::_M_run() (this=0x7fe7e4000918)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/thread:115
#10 0x00007fe7f4659070 in ?? () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#11 0x00007fe7f3aaae25 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#12 0x00007fe7f3dbdbad in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

I've stepped through in GDB watching the memory location for Curl to see if something unexpectedly rights/corrupts to it but it doesn't look like there's any issues.

Comment: That stack trace doesn't have any curl functions in it so I don't know why you're blaming curl. You're getting a segfault in the destructor of std::string. Without having a full, minimal complete example program, it's hard to do more than guess, but I'd bet you're deleting that string you allocate with new (Why are you even doing that and using a pointer to a string instead of just using a string? At the *very* least use a smart pointer instead) twice.

Comment: I tried using a normal string and trying a string pointer but the same issue. The reason I'm blaming curl because line 1 in the stack trace where it says the issue is on line at CrashInfo.cpp:732 is the `curl_easy_cleanup` I get the same thing whether I allocate a string or not. I did also try not deleting the string pointer in case that was to do with it but still get the same crash

Comment: I would be surprised if `curl_easy_cleanup` was calling a std::string destructor. Retry gdb or valgrind to get accurate information.

Comment: Hmm. Yea I've come to the conclusion its not curl. I've put a log line after the curl_easy_cleanup and it gets printed fine and then crashes. I've then put a 5 second sleep after the curl_easy_cleanup and the log line and it successfully waits and then crash again. It looks like as soon as the function ends, it seems to cause the crash with some string being cleared but I can't see why (I've removed the string pointer, its just a normal string) Valgrind and GDB isn't helping me too much at the moment :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured the issues, it was rather odd one. As Michael Doubez said in the comments it wasn't directly curl. I thought it was curl because the 2nd line in the stack track was pointing to the curl_easy_cleanup and then the top line was the string destructor so thought it was curl.

I put a log line after the curl_easy_cleanup and it logged successfully and then crashed. The curl_easy_cleanup was the last call in the method and it was when the function finished the crash happened.

I ended up commenting out the entire function and then slowly re-add chunks of it to nail down at what point it caused it to crash.

It ended up being the line `curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &httpResponseCode);`. I was passing in a pointer to an int when the function wants a pointer to a long.

I corrected the above and now everything works as expected, not entirely sure why though this didn't 1, raise a compiler warning that was I passing in the wrong type, and 2, why the stack trace was showing a string being destructed.

Comment: 1. because *setopt() is a varargs function and 2. I'm guessing: that variable was next to `httpResponseCode` on the stack?